# Is it possible to manipulate maximum callstack size in solidity?

Tags: solidity, security, ethereum-design

I'm a student learning about solidity language.

According to [solidity's official docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/security-considerations.html?highlight=depth), the maximum callstack size is 1024.

But, I am wondering, can a developer change the maximum callstack size in solidity?

If so, could you give me links to reference.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It's a language feature, so no you can't.

Comment: Just to amplify Lauri's and Shane's answers, such a modification would create a separate network because normal nodes would error out while modified nodes would presumably carry on processing transactions that _need_ the larger call stack. The divergence would create two different states, two different truths so two different Ethereum(ish) networks, a.k.a. a fork.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen & RobHitchens They were also really helpful to me. Thank for your kindness!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/security-considerations.html#callstack-depth), the maximum callstack size is 1024. This cannot be edited without forking the code and creating your own architecture.

As Lauri mentioned in the comment, it is a language feature, so you cannot edit it.

Comment: It was really helpful to me. Thank for an good explanation.